# Highstock UTC date YTD

Tags: highcharts

I use highstock to display some data on my website.
To ensure the correct date is used I have set the UTC to false from the global settings.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
            });
```

But when I use the YTD button the wrong data is selected and my date is starting from the first of february instead of january.
I can set the UTC to true, but then the date is incorrect.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9r8u/1/) for the options I have set.  How to get YTD correctly from first of January?

Comment: Because when you disable UTC, time is set as browser time.

Comment: But even if that is the case, I would expect that the YTD button is working correctly and take my timezone into account

I had added a jsfiddle, but seems to be lost during posting
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9r8u/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are passing end date of month and that's why chart showing wrong date in tooltip. Possible then pass start date of month and check.

Comment: Thank you for your tip.
It is true that disabling the UTC is causing this difference, but why is the YTD functionality not also using this UTC property?
I have modified my code so that I also set the UTC date and that seems to be working fine.
Thank you for pointing into the right direction

Comment: You are welcome. we are using Highstork in our product at very extensive level. if you have time then just check out out prodcut. http://ir.tools.investis.com/clients/%28S%28jp5ondtddrufyt4re032m23i%29%29/fi/sponda/sm7/default.aspx?nocache=1&culture=fi-FI